# How to resolve "Potential SQL Injection" risk?

Tags: sql, security, sql-injection, static-analysis

I am using Visual Code Grepper to analyse our code. In almost every SQL statement in code, it is indicating an "SQL Injection" risk. Even code lines where parameters are passed.

Take a look at this example below:

> CRITICAL: Potentially Unsafe Code - Potential SQL Injection Line: 804
> D:\Source\XXX\App_Code\Reports\QueryClass.cs The application appears to allow SQL injection via a pre-prepared dynamic SQL statement.
>
> ExecuteSQL("Update QueryParam Set Value=@VA,UpdatedBy=@UB,Updated=GetUTCDate() Where ParamID=@PID", DAL.SQLType.sqlNQ, Nothing, "@VA,@UB,@PID", Value, User.UserID,
> ParamID);

How is this risky when values are passed in parameters?

How do I resolve these "risks"?

Comment: While I don't know how the analyzer works, I too would be suspicious of this code because of how it passes the list of parameter names as a comma-separated string, instead of a `string[]` (or not at all, since the parameter names can be fairly safely derived from the statement). First thing to consider is probably if this method actually adds anything as opposed to using a dedicated micro ORM like Dapper. Failing that, you'll have to see if there's some way to annotate the `ExecuteSQL` method so the analyzer specifically recognizes it as safe when called with string literals.

Comment: Looks like the tool just detects `ExecuteSQL` and doesn't parse the string expression representing the query text. Sure potentially one can build a dangerous expression.